# nested foreach loops with switch statement not incrementing case variable

Tags: c#, foreach, switch-statement, increment

I have this code:

```
                foreach(List<string> build in Builds)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach(string item in build)
                    {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                Console.WriteLine("BuildID: " + item);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Console.WriteLine("UserID: " + item);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Console.WriteLine("Parameter 1: " + item);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Console.WriteLine("Parameter 2: " + item);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Console.WriteLine("Parameter 3: " + item);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                Console.WriteLine("Parameter 4: " + item);
                                break;
                        }
                        i++;
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                }
```

and the output is:

```
BuildID: 1
1
BuildID: 1
1
BuildID: a
1
BuildID: b
1
BuildID: c
1
BuildID: d
1
```

The items in the List are incrementing and being displayed properly (1,1,a,b,c,d) but for a reason i dont know, the incrementation of the 'i' counter is being forgotten after the switch executes? I don't understand? The expected output should be:

```
BuildID: 1
1
UserID: 1
2
Parameter 1: a
3
Parameter 2: b
4
Parameter 3: c
5
Parameter 4: d
6
```

Comment: Check your data. This fits for a list of single-item lists.

Comment: Do your builds have more than one item?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you mean? The actual data in the list is being run through properly, but the simple incrementation variable 'i' is being forgotten, nothing to do with the data in the list

Comment: @Daniel (awesome name) sometimes yes

Comment: Looks like you have many builds, all of them with only one string each.

Comment: The actual output you are getting can be explained by the fact your inner loop is only being ran once. The Visual Studio debugger is a great tool to figure problem like this out.

Comment: Your such a sweetheart, thank you for the down vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you've got multiple *lists*, but each list only has one entry.

You're declaring `i` inside the outer loop, and initializing it to 0... so the behaviour you've shown is exactly what you'd get in that situation.

This is easy to diagnose further. Just add some more logging:

```
foreach(List<string> build in Builds)
{
    Console.WriteLine("New build with {0} items", build.Count);
    int i = 0;
```

I suspect you'll see:

```
New build with 1 items
BuildID: 1
1
New build with 1 items
BuildID: 1
1
New build with 1 items
BuildID: a
1
New build with 1 items
BuildID: b
1
New build with 1 items
BuildID: c
1
New build with 1 items
BuildID: d
1
```

Assuming that's what you actually see but not what you expect to see, you then need to go back and trace where `Builds` is being created.

As an aside, your code would be much simpler as:

```
private static readonly string[] BuildItemLabels = 
    { "BuildID", "UserID", "Parameter1", "Parameter2", "Parameter3" , "Parameter4" };
...

foreach (List<string> build in Builds)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < build.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", BuildItemLabels[i], build[i]);
    }
}
```

(You should consider what would happen if a list ever had more than 6 items, mind you...)

Comment: that makes sense, i will check what is actually being sent in 'Builds'

Answer (score 2):

Well your inner loop is not working as expected. Your output is only doing `BuildId` meaning `foreach(string item in build)` the only item in each build is `BuildId`, your switch prints that, then you get to the bottom, increment i, print it and go back to the outer loop where it's set to 0. That is why it's always 1. The problem lies outside of the loops. The build lists aren't actually being populated with the data you expect them to contain.

Comment: that makes sense, i will check what is actually being sent in 'Builds'

Comment: @Dan you if you step through it I'm confident you'll find you only go through the inner loop once for each iteration of the outer loop which obviously is not the intended behavior. Once you confirm that look to where you populate the list, that's where the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In general this should not be a problem.

This code:

```
        var list1 = new List<int> {10, 20, 30};
        var list2 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

        int i = 0;

        foreach (int integ in list1)
        {
            foreach (int integ2 in list2)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine(integ + integ2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine(integ + integ2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine(integ + integ2);
                        break;
                }
            }
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Results:

```
11
12
13
1
21
22
23
2
31
32
33
3
```